# Why is my data still being added to the list?

Tags: java

Hi I'm using a GUI and adding the users input into a list from a textfield when they press a button however when the textbox is empty, im still having an empty value being added despite my if statement to try and prevent that. I have tried to use null as the condition also which does not work either.
Thanks.

```
    String data = addField.getText();

    if(data!=""){ // need to figure out why its adding blanks still
       myList.add(data);
       addField.setText("");
       System.out.println(data + " was added to the list");
    }
```

Comment: did you try debugging and inspecting the value of "data" variable?

Comment: [You can't compare strings with `==` or `!=`](/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). In your case, you could use `if (!data.isEmpty())`. That may or may not be the reason for your issue.

Comment: if(!data.equals(""))

Comment: ah yes I was not comparing them properly, thanks for the help